# How can I write a Jquery function which 'creates' or 'modifies' existing html modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I'm trying to create a confirm delete window for users who are trying to delete the existing model from my cloud panel. So I created HTML design, but now I'm stuck with the coding part, I'm really green on Jquery and JS, so I pretty much know the logic, but I can't achieve it in code.

How should it work?
When the user presses on the delete button, I somehow need to pass in the information of the model the user is trying to delete and then modify the delete window content with the model information.

What have I done for now?
I have only designed the design (HTML code), which I'm putting down here.

This is the delete window:

[image]

```
<!-- Confirm delete -->
<div class="modal fade" id="reply_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <form method="post" action="{{request.build_absolute_uri}}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal-dialog rounded" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">
                        <div class="text-danger">
                            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Please confirm your action!
                        </div>
                    </h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <span class="text-center text-dark p-3 border-bottom shadow-sm" style="background-color: #ffe88a;font-size: 14px;">Warning: This action cannot be undone</b>.</span>
                <div class="modal-body" style="background-color: #fafafa;font-family: 'Mukta', sans-serif;">
                  {% if messages %}
                  {% for message in messages %}
                  {% if message.tags == 'error' %}
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger justify-content-md-center text-center" role="alert">
                        <i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>
                        {{message.message|safe}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                  {% elif message.tags == 'success' %}
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col"></div>
                    <div class="alert alert-success col-6 justify-content-md-center text-center" role="alert">
                       <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> {{message.message|safe}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col"></div>
                </div>
                  {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}
                  {% endif %}
                  <div class="text-center pt-1">
                    <h4 class="page-title"><span class="text-danger font-weight-bold">*</span> Delete [MODAL_ID]</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="justify-content-center">
                    <form method="post" action="{% url 'ticket_list' %}">{% csrf_token %}
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-{% if request.user_agent.is_pc == True %}4{%else%}4{%endif%}">
                          <div class="text-left">
                            <img width="{% if request.user_agent.is_mobile %}100{% else %}140{% endif %}"src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/papirus-team/papirus-status/256/user-trash-icon.png" alt="qr_code">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-{% if request.user_agent.is_pc == True %}8{%else%}8{%endif%}">
                          <p class="pl-2">You are trying to delete [MODAL_ID].<br>To confirm this action please type: <span id="ticket_del_text" name="ticket_del_text" class="font-weight-bold text-dark">del [MODAL_PUBLIC_ID]</span></p>
                          <input type="text" id="code_verify"  name="code_verify" placeholder="Please enter the code" pattern="^[a-z A-Z 0-9]{5}$" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('This code does not match the regex.')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" required class="form-control text-center mb-2">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn p-2 btn-success col-12">{% if request.session.language == 'lt' %} Ištrinti {% elif request.session.language == 'en' %} Delete {% elif request.session.language == 'rus' %} вытирать {% endif %}</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have created

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change_modal(modal_name,modal_id) {
        const modal_id_span = document.getElementById('modal_id_span');
        const modal_id_span2 = document.getElementById('modal_id_span2');
        const modal_del_text = document.getElementById('ticket_del_text');

        modal_id_span.innerText = modal_id;
        modal_id_span2.innerText = modal_id;
        modal_del_text.innerText = modal_name;

        console.log('modelis', modal_name);
    }
</script>
```

And then called it with

```
<a href="#" onclick="change_modal('{{ticket.public_id}}', '{{ticket}}')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_modal">TEST</a>
```

And here's the result:)

[image]